# Increment each date value in a row based on a difference and create duplicate rows based on that

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which has start date and end date column and I have to create duplicate rows based on the date difference as well as increment the start date in each of the rows based on the difference. I have been able to make duplicate rows based on the difference but I am not able to increment the start date since the difference is fixed in each of duplicate rows

```
for s in range(0,len(Fortnight_1)):
    if Fortnight_1['Date_Difference'].iloc[s]>0:
        for i in range(0,int(Fortnight_1['Date_Difference'].iloc[s])):
            df = df.append(Fortnight_1.iloc[s])
```

By above code I have duplicated the rows based on Date_Difference. I need to put the dates in Dates column:

[image]

We need the dates column as mentioned but I am not able to increment the dates in duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#convert to datetimes
df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'])
df['End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'])

df['Date_difference'] = df['End Date'].sub(df['Start Date']).dt.days

#repeat indices by Date_difference
df1 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Date_difference'] + 1)]
        

#create ecounter converted to days timedeltas
s = pd.to_timedelta(df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='d')

#add timedeltas to Start Date and convert to DatetimeIndex
out = df1.assign(Dates = df1['Start Date'].add(s))
      
#if need days instead datetimes
out = df1.assign(Dates = df1['Start Date'].add(s).dt.day)
```